# What comparison problems can using the varchar type instead of the char type avoid?

Tags: sql, postgresql

From Database System Concepts

> **When comparing two values of type char,** if they are of different lengths extra spaces are automatically added to the shorter one to
>   make them the same size, before comparison.
>
> **When comparing a char type with a varchar type**, one may expect extra spaces  to be added to the varchar type to make the lengths
>   equal, before comparison; however, this may or may not be done,
>   depending on the database system. As a result, even if the same value
>   “Avi” is stored in the attributes A and B above, a comparison A=B may
>   return false.
>
> We recommend you always **use the varchar type instead of the char
>   type to avoid these problems.**

Could you give some examples to explain comparing two values of type char, and comparing two valus of a varchar type? What operator(s) is used in the comparison, `=`?

What problems can  using the varchar type instead of the char type avoid? Why?

This is about SQL in general, and I guess it may also apply to PostgreSQL, since it is compatible with SQL standard well.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Comment: Is this book just trying to say that `char(n)` is always right-padded with spaces to be `n` characters long whereas `varchar(n)` isn't? Anyway, the usual approach with PostgreSQL is to use `text` or `varchar` (without the `(n)` part) and let the database deal with optimizing table layout and storage on disk; if you need to enforce a specific size then a CHECK constraint tends to serve you better than embedding that in the column definition. Also read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to use `char` nowadays. That is true for every relational DBMS out there. The `char` type is a left-over from the "old age" where it was more efficient to use fixed-length values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue is that `char` will pad the value with spaces and this can lead to some surprising and inconsistent results.

Here we see Postgres retains the trailing space.

```
test=> create table foo ( c char(10), v varchar(10) );
CREATE TABLE

test=> insert into foo values ('foo', 'foo');
INSERT 0 1

test=> select * from foo;
     c      |  v  
------------+-----
 foo        | foo

test=> select concat(c, '>'), concat(v, '>') from foo where c = 'foo     ';
   concat    | concat 
-------------+--------
 foo       > | foo>
```

But MySQL does not unless `PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH` is set.

```
mysql> create table foo ( c char(10), v varchar(10) );

mysql> insert into foo values ('foo', 'foo');

mysql> select * from foo;
+------+------+
| c    | v    |
+------+------+
| foo  | foo  |
+------+------+

mysql> select concat(c, '>'), concat(v, '>') from foo where c = 'foo     ';
+----------------+----------------+
| concat(c, '>') | concat(v, '>') |
+----------------+----------------+
| foo>           | foo>           |
+----------------+----------------+

mysql> set sql_mode = 'PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH';

mysql> select concat(c, '>'), concat(v, '>') from foo where c = 'foo     ';
+----------------+----------------+
| concat(c, '>') | concat(v, '>') |
+----------------+----------------+
| foo       >    | foo>           |
+----------------+----------------+
```

[The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) outlines several issues.

> Values of type character are physically padded with spaces to the specified width n, ***and are stored and displayed that way***.
>
> ...trailing spaces are treated as semantically insignificant and disregarded when comparing two values of type character. In collations where whitespace is significant, this behavior can produce unexpected results; for example `SELECT 'a '::CHAR(2) collate "C" < E'a\n'::CHAR(2)` returns true, even though C locale would consider a space to be greater than a newline
>
> Trailing spaces are removed when converting a character value to one of the other string types.

Storage engines have improved such that there's little reason to use `char` anymore.

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; ***in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs.*** In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

One case where `char` *might* be justified is to store very small, fixed size strings. For example, [ISO 2 character country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) might be stored as `char(2)`. But the performance difference is unlikely to be noticed on such small strings.

`char` is a headache best avoided.